# While trying to download file from mongoDB gridfs - MongoRuntimeError: FileNotFound: file <FILENAME> was not found

Tags: javascript, mongoose, download, multer, gridfs

I'm creating a MERN app that allows the user to submit doc/docx/pdf files.
I'm working with multer, multer-gridfs-storage, gridfs-stream (or at least trying to)
and I have succeeded at the uploading aspect part, but when I try to download the file by id or name this error accrue:

MongoRuntimeError: FileNotFound: file 76e30bdcc81918984f4318eeb2af3ff0.docx was not found

I'm new to gridfs and multer, so I'm probably doing something wrong, if anyone could help I appreciate it.

I triple-checked and file exists, with the same Id and the same name.

useful info:

server.ts, my mongoose connection and bucket:

```
export let gfs;

mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

mongoose
  .connect(mongodb_uri)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("At mongoose.connect:");
    console.error(err.message);
  });

export const conn = mongoose.connection;

 conn.once("open", () => {
  gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
    bucketName: "cvfiles",
  });
});
```

my files routes:

```
import express from "express";
import {
  downloadResume,
  saveFileToUser,
  uploadMiddleware,
  uploader,
} from "./cvCtrl";

const router = express.Router();

router
  .get("/download/:filename", downloadResume)
  .post("/upload", uploadMiddleware, uploader, saveFileToUser);

export default router;
```

cvCtrl.ts

```
import multer from "multer";
import { GridFsStorage } from "multer-gridfs-storage";
import path from "path";
import CvModel from "./cvfilesModel";
const crypto = require("crypto");
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
import fs from "fs"

import { gfs } from "../../server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const mongodb_uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;

export const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongodb_uri,
  options: {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads",
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  },
});
export const store = multer({
  storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 20000000 },
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

export function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  const fileTypes = /doc|docx|pdf/;
  const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
  if (mimetype && extname) return cb(null, true);
  cb("filetype");
}

export const uploadMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const upload = store.single("file");
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: "file to large" });
    } else if (err) {
      if (err === "filetype")
        return res.status(400).send("Only doc, docx, pdf is expeccted.");
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    next();
  });
};

export async function uploader(req, res, next) {
  const { file } = req;
  if (file.size > 20000000) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "file may not exceed 20mb" });
  }
  //   console.log("uploaded file: ", file);
  req.addFile = file;
  next();
}

export async function saveFileToUser(req, res) {
  const { file, addFile } = req;
  const { title, description, userId } = req.body;
  const cvFileDB = new CvModel({
    userId: userId,
    fileId: addFile.id,
    fileDescription: description,
    fileName: title,
    fileInfo: file
  });
  await cvFileDB.save();
  res.send({ file });
}

export const downloadResume = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {filename} = req.params
    // const _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(fileId)
    gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(filename).
    pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

The error accrued in the downloadResume function, no matter if I use openDownloadStreamByName(filename) with the file name that has been modified to be unique,
or with openDownloadStream(fileId), that has been used with a the file Id that appers as the _id in the uploads.files collection, example for both:

```
export const downloadResume = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {filename} = req.params
    gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(filename).
    pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

or by Id:

```
export const downloadResume = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {fileId} = req.params
    const _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(fileId)
    gfs.openDownloadStream(_id).
    pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

if you have any ideas or maybe code to read, I'd really appreciate it!